# Laravel Join Tables by date sum of colums

Tags: php, laravel, join, sum

I have two tables with these structures:

Table: Income

```
id  | Date  | IncomeAmount
```

Table: Expenses

```
id  | Date  | ExpenseAmount
```

I have multiple registers during a day so I need to add by day the fields `IncomeAmount` and `ExpenseAmount` and show something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu07F.jpg)

```
Date       | IncomeAmount | ExpenseAmount | Balance
2018-01-01 | 10           | 5             | 5
2018-01-02 | 0            | 5             | -5
2018-01-03 | 20           | 0             | 20
```

As in the example, is possible for certains days not having registers for the IncomeAmount or the ExpenseAmount fields.

Any advice on how to achieve this is very appreciated.

Excuse me for my english.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code do you already have? Do you use models?

Comment: what is the relation between two table?

Comment: These two tables have not relation in the models, the relation in this case would be the date when the registers were created. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want days without income or expenses in your result?

Comment: If the day has at least one income or one expense register yes, but if the day doesn´t have any register of them, then not.

Comment: This might be useful for you.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801133/mysql-pivot-query-with-sum-of-column-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you received new income run this query and also update your daily table: (you have not mentioned table name, so just change it)

```
$today = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

Income::insert([
    'Date' => $today,
    'IncomeAmount' => $income
]);

$today_report = ReportTable::where(['date', $today])->get()[0];
$today_report->IncomeAmount = $today_report->IncomeAmount + $income;
$today_report->balance = $today_report->IncomeAmount - $today_report->ExpenseAmount;
$today_report->save();
```

if you receive new expence:

```
$today = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

Expense::insert([
    'Date' => $today,
    'ExpenseAmount' => $expense
]);

$today_report = ReportTable::where(['date', $today])->get()[0];
$today_report->ExpenseAmount = $today_report->ExpenseAmount + $income;
$today_report->balance = $today_report->IncomeAmount - $today_report->ExpenseAmount;
$today_report->save();
```

I think That's what you need.
note to have models

```
Income, Expense, ReportTable
```

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**

```
$incomes = Income::select('*', DB::raw('SUM(incomeAmount) as incomeAmount'))
->groupBy('date')
->get()
->pluck('incomeAmount','date');

$expenses = Expense::select('*', DB::raw('SUM(expenseAmount) as expenseAmount'))
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->get()
        ->pluck('expenseAmount','date');

$day_balance = $income['2018-15-06'] - $income['2018-15-06'];
```

Comment: Wild `ReportTable` appeared!

Comment: I said that models is necessary or he can use `DB::table('tablename');`

Comment: So your advice is to create a new table for repeating data?

Comment: you are right, thanks. I thought he needed to create new report table. I'll edit my answer now. thanks

Comment: maybe you don't have any expenses or invome in 2018-12-04 so check it with isset

Comment: It worked! Thanks, you were right the date I was testing didn´t have any records, the problem I facing now is when showing the results in the view.  I'm getting this result array:31 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "Date" => "2017-12-01"
    "Incomes" => "392500"
    "Expenses" => 188750
    "day_balance" => 203750
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▶]
  2 => array:4 [▶]
  3 => array:4 [▶]
 .
 .
 .
  30 => array:4 [▶]
]    but when passing this to blade I got "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given", what could be the problem?

Comment: it would be better to show me your code, where you are passing array to blade